# Height parameter not working with one of my images in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, height

When adding images to a table, I was able to size the first image's width and height but for some reason the second image will not register the height in the image tag. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="pic"><a href="link to image on Facebook here> <img src="pic1FileName.jpg" width="150" height="200" alt="text"></a></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="pic2"><a link to image on Facebook> <img src="pic2FileName" width="150 height="200" alt="text"></a></p>
        </td>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is with the `height="200"` that is not registering in my code.  I'm using SublimeText and the height also doesn't change to green like the height in my first image. 
I can also post the CSS code if needed, but this is kind of a personal project so I want to post as little of it as I possibly can.

Comment: Please, remove words solved from your question and accept correct answer or write your own and note that question is solved in comment

Comment: Okay! I will do that.

Comment: Generally if your code completion/color coding stops working it's a good indication that you've missed something simple like a closing quote, curly brace, semicolon, etc. It's telling you to take a closer look. Sublime is usually good about auto-closing quotes & brackets for you (unless you've turned that feature off...), but you can always type open/closing quotes/braces/brackets yourself & then fill in between them. Avoids issues like this.

Comment: Yeah I'm very new to Sublime and am still figuring out some of its really cool features so I feel that in time when I get experienced with it I can master the program and write a lot more efficient and  organized code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing quotation in your second image, after width.

```
<img src="pic2FileName" width="150 height="200" alt="text">
```

Should be:

```
<img src="pic2FileName" width="150" height="200" alt="text">
```

Comment: Oh, thats embarassing.  Thank you and sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: @TedMazer no worries, welcome to Stack Overflow :) Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it helped.

Comment: I will as soon as I can.  I'm not that new to Stack I used it for Java for a while but forgot my account information so I had to make a new one :(